# Compilation errors after migrating to Visual Studio 2013: X is not a member of Y_aspx

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

We're trying to upgrade a large **VS2010** solution to **VS2013**, and among the various issues, this one seems the most confusing.
The solution worked at first, but after a couple of builds, we started getting

> error BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.main_[whateverpage]_aspx'

This is an issue that used to happen occasionally with VS10, but it would always be fixed with a clean & rebuild. Now it simply refuses to go away.

Additionally, if you create a function called `InitializeCulture` in the `aspx.vb` file, it will simply show an error about some other property of either the page we're trying to open or the base Page class. It's as if the generated `ASP.main_whateverpage_aspx` class doesn't see the members of the classes it inherits from. What could be causing this?

Edit: We've discovered that this only happens on pages which inherit our myPage class (a simple extension of Page with a couple of common methods).  This class is inside its own project, which was untouched by VS when it was migrating. Moving the class to the Main project makes the error go away, but I'd rather not do that unless I at least know why.

Comment: Have you visited [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54a40a36-209a-46ee-b834-df946532719f/bc30456-initializeculture-is-not-a-member-of-fixes?forum=clr)? I think it could be helpful.

Comment: @BishopBarber: I have. Unfortunately, this seems to be a really common error with a whole bunch of different causes, and none of the solutions I've found there or elsewhere on the internet have helped.

Comment: Did you make sure you have no code behind files with the same class name?

Comment: I did. I even deleted all the other code branches from my workspace in case they were somehow messing with my build. No go.

Comment: Do you, by chance, have specified the `src` attribute in your pages directives?

Comment: I don't. I have, however, come across some new information, so do check out the latest edit if you have the time.